# How to return custom data from api-platform?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I’m beginner in symfony and api-platform. I try to implement a solution that allow to return custom data instead of api-platform response.

I try [custom controller](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) and [HttpFoundation\Response](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) but unable to implement/manage it.

Here is my code :

**Task.php in APP\Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\TaskController;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(itemOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "post_publication"={
 *         "method"="POST",
 *         "path"="/tasks",
 *         "controller"=TaskController::class,
 *     "read"=false,
 *     }
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TaskRepository")
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @Groups("tasks")
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */ 
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $priority;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    public  $user;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTime(): ?string
    {
        return $this->time;
    }

    public function setTime(string $time): self
    {
        $this->time = $time;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriority(): ?string
    {
        return $this->priority;
    }

    public function setPriority(string $priority): self
    {
        $this->priority = $priority;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user
     */
    public function setUser($user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


}
```

**TaskController.php in App\Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class TaskController extends Task
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function __invoke(Task $data): Task
    {

        $result["success"] = true;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Here is **the answer** **i get after a post method on api/tasks**

```
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Task",
    "@id": "\/api\/tasks\/17",
    "@type": "Task",
    "user": null,
    "id": 17,
    "name": "string",
    "time": "string",
    "priority": "string"
}
```

Here is **the answer i would like to return** when endpoint is call :

> { "success": true, "message": "successfully send" }

I hope that it's clear, if not, let me know, thanks by advance

Comment: post needs to be in collectionOperations, not itemOperations

Comment: Thank's for the answer, now i got -> Return value of App\\Controller\\TaskController::__invoke() must be an instance of App\\Entity\\Task , look like i only can return an instance of Task and none of custom return

Comment: In fact you need to cheat it to work, so this will be bad practice, because it is not intended to work the way you want (although I had similar case like you once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Api-platform is not designed for such things you have to cheat it by implicitly adding the resource definitions as request attributes:

```php
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="task",
     *     path="/task",
     *     methods={"POST","OPTIONS"},
     *     defaults={
     *          "_api_resource_class"=Task::class,
     *          "_api_collection_operation_name"="post"
     *     }
     * )
     * @param Task $data
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function __invoke(Task $data): JsonResponse {
        return new JsonResponse('task success json', 201);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for your help ! It's working !